# Firebase database Doesn't stop updating value

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a chat app and I am trying to check if the user has seen a message or not. The app works fine for the user who has sent the message first but for the user who has sent the message after the first user, it keeps updating.

**Here is the database structure**

[image]

So, The value `seen` keeps updating between `true and false` for `MFRVfDa3JrFi8Gg9aL2` which was sent by the second user.

**Here is the Code**

```
ValueEventListener seenListener;
private void seenMessage(String qid) {
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Message");

    seenListener = db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot childdshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Chats chat = childdshot.getValue(Chats.class);
                        if (chat.getReceiverID().equals(userId) && chat.getSenderId().equals(qid)) {
                            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap.put("seen", true);
                            childdshot.getRef().updateChildren(hashMap);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}
```

So, What should I do to stop it from updating itself again and again?

Comment: Where is the code that sets "seen" to false?  Whatever code that does that will trigger this callback again, and cause another write.

Answer (score 3):

Your `addValueEventListener` gets triggered immediately with the current value, and then every time something changes. Since you change the value in `onDataChange`, that triggers the listener again, and again, and...

To only read the value once and update it you'll want to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead `addValueEventListener`.